# sql query exact search than others

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table that has many columns. But we consider here 2 columns.
Name is **Column1** and **Column2**. And table name is **WordTable**. I just want to search 50 record bases on those 2 column that match like below.

If I enter **"auto**" then result should be.

```
"auto"
"autoa"
"autoab"
.
.
.
Etc
```

If I enter **"maver"**, result should be

```
"maver"
"mavera"
"maverr"
"maverx"
"maverydsdb"
```

Means First word should exact match the rest of after ascending order. And match should be done from any of the tow columns.

Below are my query but doesn't work.

```
searchWord(value) async {
    var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT *
    FROM WordTable
    WHERE (Column1 LIKE '$value%' OR Column2 LIKE '$value%')
    ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 ASC
    LIMIT 50");

    List<Word> list =
    res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Word.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];
    return list;
  }
```

Getting result but not in expect order.

Where I'm going wrong? Pls guide me.

> I'm coming from mobile platform and using "SQFLite" data base so for me query is important.

Comment: I'm from mobile platform I'm using "SQFlite" for Flutter So. for me query is important.

Comment: No result or not expect order?

Comment: @RyanNghiem I'm getting result but not expect order

Comment: @Govaadiyo . . . If your table has two columns, why does `select *` only return one column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I can't get you. Actually my table has more than 2 columns but I want to search result to be get by those 2 columns.exact Aim is match should be first.

Comment: @Govaadiyo . . . I cannot figure out what you are asking.  You say there are two columns that you care about, but your results only show one column.  I have no idea what the real data structure is or what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are two tricks here. The first is to order by something that doesn't actually exist in the table, ie the part of the word after "$value". You can use [sqlite substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [sqlite length](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) to find that part, something like `substr(column,length($value))`. Since the desired result is the "whole" word, it can be put back together with concatenation operator `||`, something like `$value||substr(column,length($value))`.

The second trick is to select `column1` OR `column2` into the same result field so they can be ordered as one column. One way to accomplish that would be with a `UNION` query.

With data like this:

```
column1     column2
----------  ----------
autob       autoa
mavery      autoc
maverz      mavera
autoz       maverq
autoa       autob
```

This query:

```
select 'auto'||substr(column1,length('auto') + 1) word
from wordTable
where column1 like 'auto%'
UNION
select 'auto'||substr(column2,length('auto')+1)
from wordTable
where column2 like 'auto%'
order by 1
```

Returns this result:

```
word
----------
autoa
autob
autoc
autoz
```

**ADDENDUM**

Upon further reflection, I rather overthunk it. The first "trick" is moot if you use the UNION with the matching "words" in the same result column as with:

```
SELECT column1,* 
from wordTable
where column1 like '$value%'
UNION
SELECT column2,*
from wordTable
where column2 like '$value%'
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `+` connect string to fill your parameter otherwise you will only execute this sql.

```
SELECT * FROM WordTable WHERE (Column1 LIKE '$value%' OR Column2 LIKE '$value%') ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 ASC LIMIT 50
```

I am not sure what language you use I would suggest you use parameters to avoid sql-injection.

```
"SELECT * FROM WordTable WHERE (Column1 LIKE '"+$value+"%' OR Column2 LIKE '"+$value%+"') ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 ASC LIMIT 50"
```

Comment: $value% is for me .. let me change my question little bit.

Comment: @Govaadiyo What language did you use on mobile platform

Comment: I'm using dart language

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for order:

```
SELECT *
FROM WordTable
WHERE (Column1 LIKE '$value%' OR Column2 LIKE '$value%')
ORDER BY Column1 = '$value' DESC, Column1 LIKE '$value%' DESC, 
Column2 = '$value' DESC, Column2 LIKE '$value%' DESC, 
Column1 ASC, Column2 ASC
LIMIT 50
```